# Why is this createAsyncThunk behaving strangely?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have some issues with this `createAsyncThunk` from the redux toolkit API

```
export const getPayments = createAsyncThunk('getPayments/all', async ({ rejectWithValue }) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`/payments`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        })
        console.log('res:', response)
        return response
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('ERROR:', e)
        rejectWithValue(e)
    }
})
```

Whenever I add `rejectWithValue` as a parameter, it ALWAYS shows as rejected in the redux devtools. and when I remove it, it's ALWAYS fulfilled. what is going on here? I just want to call this function below if there is an error from the fetch? why is it always rejecting it?

EDIT: I am seeing this `Cannot destructure property 'rejectWithValue' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.` in the response now, which makes sense why it's always rejected, why is this happening though and how do I fix it?

Comment: I think you should add first attribute to your async function, for instance:
async (data, { rejectWithValue })...

Comment: @AlekseyDubinskiy but I don't need any data in this instance?

Comment: even if i put in data, it still fires "fulfilled" even though it jumps in the catch block??

Comment: You also need to return the rejection. `return rejectWithValue(e)`

Comment: Even if you need no data, `thunkApi` will be passed in as the second argument into that function. So like everywhere in JavaScript: if you care about the second argument and not the first, you still need to give the first one a name, or you'll never get to a second argument. Not necessarily `data`. `_` might be a good choice to indicate you don't care about it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example how you can do it, as commented  the `rejectWithValue` of the [payload creator](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator) is a property of the **second argument**  and the payload creator needs to **return** the result of the `rejectWithValue` call, here is an example:

```
// toggle reject
const reject = ((shouldReject) => () =>
  (shouldReject = !shouldReject))(true);
// test thunk action creator
const testAsyncThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'some/test',
  //  arg is the argument passed to the action creator, can be ignored if not used
  async (arg, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    console.log('argument passed to action creator:', arg);
    if (reject()) {
      //return result of rejectWithValue call
      return rejectWithValue('rejected');
    }
    return Promise.resolve('resolved');
  }
);
```

When you dispatch a thunk created with `createAsyncThunk` the resulting promise [will not reject](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-results) unless you use `unwrapResult`.

Here is a minimal app demonstrating the behaviour:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
  createAsyncThunk,
  unwrapResult,
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import { Provider, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {
  createStore,
  applyMiddleware,
  compose,
} from 'redux';

// toggle reject
const reject = ((shouldReject) => () =>
  (shouldReject = !shouldReject))(true);
// test thunk action creator
const testAsyncThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  'some/test',
  //  arg is the argument passed to the action creator, can be ignored if not used
  async (arg, { rejectWithValue }) => {
    console.log('argument passed to action creator:', arg);
    if (reject()) {
      //return result of rejectWithValue call
      return rejectWithValue('rejected value');
    }
    return Promise.resolve('resolved value');
  }
);

const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  return state;
};
//creating store with redux devtools and thunk middleware
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  {},
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(
      ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => (action) =>
        //minimal implementation of thunk middleware
        typeof action === 'function'
          ? action(dispatch, getState)
          : next(action)
    )
  )
);
const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() =>
        dispatch(testAsyncThunk('argument passed'))
          .then(
            (resolved) => {
              console.log('action resolved with', resolved);
              return resolved;
            },
            (rejected) =>
              // this never executes because promise returned
              //   by dispatch(tunkaction) will not reject
              console.log('action rejected with:', rejected)
          )
          .then(
            //after unwrap result you have a promise that will
            //  reject
            unwrapResult
          )
          .catch((err) =>
            console.log('rejected with...', err)
          )
      }
    >
      dispatch action
    </button>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: ok thanks. I fixed it but I have a question. I had a fetch inside `createAsyncThunk` and I put a try catch inside it and it never "rejected" it. even when it went into the catch block. BUT when I removed the try/catch and just returned the result from fetch. it worked? (i.e. based on the server response it either went to `.fulfilled` or `.rejected`. why did the try/catch not work?

Comment: @RedBaron Are you sure you **return** `return rejectWithValue(someError);` in your catch block?

Comment: nope I guess that might have worked. will try later n let you know